# Sort an ordered list by rating (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, web

Long story short, my website contains a list of hotels that have few infos. I wanna sort the ordered list of hotels by one of those infos e.g. by rating. I did some research and still couldn't find the right js algorithm for it to make it work.

```
<ol>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="hotel-container">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <h1>A</h1>
        <div class="rating"><span>3.8</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="hotel-container">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <h1>B</h1>
        <div class="rating"><span>4.5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="hotel-container">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <h1>C</h1>
        <div class="rating"><span>2.2</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried with the JavaScript so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array from the items and use sort() on the array then append each item in the sorted array back into the parent.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ol'),
items = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll('.item'));

items.sort((a,b)=>{
    const [ratA, ratB]  = [a,b].map(el=> el.querySelector('.rating span').textContent)
    return ratB - ratA;// descending sort
});

items.forEach(el => list.append(el))
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="hotel-container">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <h1>A</h1>
        <div class="rating"><span>3.8</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="hotel-container">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <h1>B</h1>
        <div class="rating"><span>4.5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="hotel-container">
      <div class="hotel-info">
        <h1>C</h1>
        <div class="rating"><span>2.2</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this rating stored in json form in a database somewhere it should be as simple as sorting an array of objects `hotels.sort((a, b) => b.rating -> a.rating);` and then rendering that array out. This is probably the most efficient method of doing this. Also note that if you have thousands of hotels to sort you might considering doing this in the backend.